# display json array data on page angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a post function that gets my json.

I want to print out all the

`max_slots`, `base_image` and `c_name` as they are in a array I am trying to loop though save value to scope to use in my HTML.

Am I doing this right ? if not whats the best way to do this ?

**OBJECTIVE**

display the results of the json array post in my html

**What I am trying**

```
$scope.c_name = [0];
      $scope.GetData = function () {
            $http({
                url: "http://www.ccuktech.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/getCampaign",
                method: "POST",
                date: {},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }).then(function (data) {
                // success
                console.log('you have received the data ');
                console.log(data);
                // $scope.base_image = response.base_image; $scope.c_name = response.c_name;
                $scope.c_name = data.data.c_name;
                // for(var i = 0; i < c_name.length; i++) {
                //     var obj = c_name[i];
                //
                //     console.log(obj.id);
                // }
                // $scope.max_slots = data.data.max_slots;
                // $scope.slot_image = data.slots.base_image;
                // console.log($scope.c_name);
            }, function (response) {
                // failed
                console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
                console.log(response);
            });
        };
```

**My HTML**

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
<h2>name</h2>:
{{c_name}}

<h2>max slots</h2>:
{{max_slots}}

<h2>image</h2>:
{{base_image}}
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $scope.GetData = function () {
            $http({
                url: "http://www.####.co.uk/####/####/####",
                method: "POST",
                date: {},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }).then(function (data) {
                // success
                console.log('you have received the data ');
                console.log(data);
                // $scope.base_image = response.base_image; $scope.c_name = response.c_name;
                // $scope.c_name = data.data.c_name;
                for(var i = 0; i < c_name.length; i++) {
                    var obj = c_name[i];

                    console.log(obj.id);
                }
                // $scope.max_slots = data.data.max_slots;
                // $scope.slot_image = data.slots.base_image;
                // console.log($scope.c_name);
            }, function (response) {
                // failed
                console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
                console.log(response);
            });
        };

        $scope.GetData();
```

**console.log(data) result**

[image]

Comment: try `data[0].max_slots`, `data[0].c_name ` and `data[0].slots[0].base_image`

Comment: @Beep I would first create an element directive that will display one element from that array and then use an ng-repeat on data received from that API. This solution is if I understood well and you want to display more similar objects from the same array

Comment: @Cosmin Ok I think I know what you mean, so ng-repeat would perform the loop ?

Comment: have you tried `data.data[0].max_slots`?

Comment: @Beep yes. In then statement from http request you would need to assign the data to your scope to have the data accessible in the template e.g $scope.myList = data; and then in template you can perform the loop on directive that you've constructed like: <span ng-repeat="data in myList"><my-new-element name="{{data.c_name}}" slots="{{max_slots}}"/></span> something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `data` in your API response is an Array. You can not just retrieve the values with **dots**

Try changing `$scope.c_name = data.data.c_name;` with `$scope.c_name = data.data[0].c_name;` and so on.

OR

```
$scope.responseData = data.data[0];
```

And in your **html**

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
 <h2>name</h2>:
 {{responseData.c_name}}

 <h2>max slots</h2>:
 {{responseData.max_slots}}

 <h2>image</h2>:
 {{responseData.base_image}}
</body>
```

**EDIT: Considering chance for occurring more than one element in `data` array**

```
$scope.responseData = data.data;
```

and in the HTML:

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-repeat="data in responseData">
    <h2>name</h2>:
    {{data.c_name}}

    <h2>max slots</h2>:
    {{data.max_slots}}

    <h2>image</h2>:
    {{data.base_image}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: surly as its a array ng-repeat will need to come into play

Comment: If you are sure that there is a chance for more than one element in the API response, yes `ng-repeat` is needed. Even though it's only one element, usage of `ng-repeat` is preferred

Comment: there will be multiple names, max slots and images so ng-repeat for all ?

Comment: According to the response structure `c_name` and `max_slots` are strings. That won't be an array. If there are multiple names, that should come in different array elements. But if you want to show `d_text` also, then you have to `ng-repeat` the **data** inside the `ng-repeat` of `responseData` since it's an array